# PHP - Should I sanitize $_FILES["filename"]["tmp_name"]

Tags: php

Before I call move_uploaded_file, should I do anything about this specific variable:

`$_FILES["filename"]["tmp_name"]`

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not much you can do with the variable itself, but you should test the file to ensure that it is of the type you were expecting—an image, for example.  Never rely on the file extension for determining the file type.  Don't, for example, assume that something with a `.jpg` extension is actually a JPEG file.

Comment: Hello Mike,

I do check the file extension and only allow a jpg, png, jpeg, tiff etc. image format. How do I know whether the image file is really an image file? I need to server this file later to the user as a headshot.

thank you

Comment: Probably the simplest way, if you have access to the [ImageMagick library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php), is to attempt to load the image file into a new IMagick object.  See the first section of [this PHPro tutorial](http://phpro.org/tutorials/Imagick.html) for an example. It is possible to use the [GD library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) to do the same sort of thing, but it's a bit more awkward.  See here for an example: http://www.bitrepository.com/how-to-validate-an-image-upload.html

Answer (score 4):

No. That's generated and assigned by PHP, and will be useless/invalid the moment your script exits, as PHP will delete any uploaded files which you have not dealt with yet. It'll be something like "/tmp/a34632rsfd234". There's no point in preserving its value. However, `$_FILES['filename']['name']` is the original filename of the file from the client's machine, and if you're preseving that, then you need to treat it as toxic waste and sanitize it.

Answer (score 1):

No because the value in there will always be a valid filename for the file system (since it points to a file on the disk).